# Strftime not updating to the correct date

Tags: ruby, sinatra, strftime

I have a sinatra app that has a small message that I want to say Happy "DayOfWeek" however I am noticing that it doesn't display the correct day for the page, it prints the previous one.
The code is extremely simple:

```
<%= "Happy #{Time.now.strftime("%A")}" %>
```

I thought it had something to do with the request response cycle, but I switched browsers and I got the same issue in chrome, firefox, and safari. Anyone have an idea of what is going on?

Comment: Are you sure this is `strftime` messing up? Or is `Time.now` also showing the date for yesterday? Also, you're missing a closing `)`.

Comment: You probably have a timezone problem.

Comment: Ok so I printed out Time.now in both the production code and my local machine, and this is what I've got: Time.now in development will print my local time, (EST) but in production Time.now is printing pacific time. I am assuming this is due to the site being cloud hosted on the west coast thus getting the time of where it is hosted.

Comment: Do you always want to display a specific time zone (EST)? Or the local time of your visitors? If the former, then you could just replace `Time.now` with `(Time.now + 10800)`, changing the value to match whatever time offset you want. If the latter, then I'm unsure what server-side solution you could find.

Answer (score 0):

from slide #28 of the presentation [Sinatra: The Classiest of Prototypes](http://www.slideshare.net/bkerley/sinatra-the-classiest-of-prototypes), by [Bryce Kerley](https://github.com/bkerley), you see the following:

```
require 'sinatra'
require 'tzinfo'

mt = TZInfo::Timezone.get('America/New_York')

get '/time' do
  mt.now.strftime "%D %T"
end
```

that should do it.